# run code when Gifu has finished animating

Tags: swift, animation, completionhandler

I've installed Gifu into my project to manage some gif animations.

Does anyone know how to run code when 1 loop of the animation is finished?

I seem to get the completion handled code running at the same time as the animation.

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    animatedDone.animate(withGIFNamed: "animatedTick.gif")
    animatedDone.prepareForAnimation(withGIFNamed: "animatedTick.gif", loopCount: 1) { (Void) in
        saveAndExit()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This callback is only for preparing animation. It's not is the callback invoked when animation completed. I found solution for this situation is dispatch a queue after animation duration.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let animatedDone = GIFImageView()
    animatedDone.prepareForAnimation(withGIFNamed: "animatedTick.gif", loopCount: 1)


    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
        animatedDone.startAnimatingGIF()
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5 + animatedDone.gifLoopDuration, execute: { // dispatch main or global
            saveAndExit()
        })
    })
}
```